# Trying to query the database for a list of badwords. Need help with query

Tags: php, filtering

I have the following code, How can I query the database for the bad words and the replacements and make it work.

```
$ad_title2 = $ad_title;
$ad_body2  = $ad_body;
$wordlist = "sh%t:cr*p|dang:d*ng|shoot:sh**t";
$words = explode('|', $wordlist);
foreach ($words as $word) {
    list($match, $replacement) = explode(':', $word);
    $ad_title2 = preg_replace("/([^a-z^A-Z]?)($match)([^a-z^A-Z]?)/i", "$1".$replacement."$3", $ad_title2);
    $ad_body2 = preg_replace("/([^a-z^A-Z]?)($match)([^a-z^A-Z]?)/i", "$1".$replacement."$3", $ad_body2);
}
```

Here is my table structure
Table name is badwords

I have 3 columns

id | word | r_word

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Get all your badwords and put them in memory. It'll always be more efficient to look for the badwords in the text, that looking for every word in the text, into the database.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry = "SELECT id, word FROM badwords WHERE (word = '{$input}' OR word LIKE '%{$input}%'";
```